# Error: "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'", but there is no 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

#### I am trying to print all the items but there is an error:

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`

#### I have no clue why it is giving this error.

I am using float for price and int for quantity, because it initialises as a string by default, which will give another error because strings are not allowed as inputs for price and quantity.

```
import csv

class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8 # The pay rate after 20% discount
    all = []
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        # Run validations to the received arguments
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} is below 0!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Price {price} is below 0!"


        # Assign to self object
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity


        # Actions to execute
        Item.all.append(self)


    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def apply_discount(self):
        self.price = self.price * self.pay_rate

    @classmethod
    def instantiate_from_csv(cls):
        with open('items.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            items = list(reader)

        for item in items:

            Item(
                name=item.get('name'),
                price=float(item.get('price')),
                quantity=int(item.get('quantity')),
                )


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item('{self.name}', {self.price}, {self.quantity})"

Item.instantiate_from_csv()
print(Item.all)
```

#### CSV File:

```
name , price , quantity
"Phone" , 100 , 1
"Laptop" , 1000 , 3
"Cable" , 10 , 5
"Mouse" , 50 , 5
"Keyboard" , 75 , 5
```

Comment: Which csv package do you use?

Comment: What's with the weird whitespace in your CSV file?

Comment: `name , price , quantity` This header line has unquoted spaces, therefore the column names also have spaces.  Try `' price '`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true is **the example csv data** cause the key name of item is ' price ' (which with the space).

So item.get('price') will return default value **None** because it could not match ' price '.

Comment: Removing the spaces in the CSV file solved it. Thank you!